# jQuery Mobile button to open directions in Apple Maps

Tags: jquery-mobile, apple-maps

I have a jQuery Mobile web application have I would like to open directions from X to Y in the web version of apple maps to be available in every devices, it this possible?

If so, how can I build a button to link to the directions apple map?

Thanks.

Comment: i guess you need to use phonegap/cordova to have access to mobile-device components.

Comment: Hi Omar, and using a web app from safari or chrome in the phone?

Comment: By saying every devices, do you mean even androids? And do you want the button to open a map in the jQuery mobile app or do you want the actual iPhone map app to open?

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks. I want to open the app in the Phone. I don't have much experience in Android but if it could open in both it could be great.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) is explained how to open stuff in the Maps app. This is what you're looking for:

> The following examples show the strings you would use in Safari and in
>   a native app to show a map of the city of Cupertino, California in the
>   Maps app.

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>
```

As for Android devices: Apple maps isn't going to work here of course, clicking the above link would lead to the website as usual.

**EDIT**

I've created a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeX6q/2/). The following link seems to always open Apple Maps on both my iPhone (iOS7) and iPad (iOS7) and it will even open Apple Maps on OSX Mavericks.

```
<a href="maps://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino">
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but even in the iPhone it's going to the Google Maps Application.

Comment: Ok, so I will have to test the device to present diferent links regarding the device, correct?

Comment: @Patrick You may have to, yes. But I'm guessing this should work on all iOS devices with Apple Maps, not 100% sure though. And for Android this will probably not work, but I haven't tested it.